# how would i import Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy into build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

how would i import Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy into build.gradle, i am unfamiliar with working with gradle and need this for a project

Answer (score 1):

Quick note: The JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy is included in all Java Versions starting with 8u161 and subsequently is no longer necessary to install manually for Java versions released 2018 or later.

If for any reason you actually have to work with an older JDK I'm afraid Gradle won't be much of a help to install the policy extensions. Since those have to installed into the JDKs security folder this is not so much a build task but more of a topic for your infrastructure setup

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u161-relnotes.html

Comment: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=jdk-8170157

Answer (score 0):

You use the `implementation` key word for that followed after the dependency you want.
Here is an example for that:

```
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.70'
```